# Stylus iterate string

Tags: css, string, iteration, stylus

I wanted to put all my media-queries into an object, and then loop over them. It works well, but the stylus forcing my output between brackets. 
My question is there were a way to remove the brackets and the quotation marks?

My code:

```
$maxBreakpoints = {
  "0": 'and (min-width: 1701px) and (max-width: 1920px)',
  "1": 'and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1700px)',
  "2": 'and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1439px)',
  "3": 'and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1023px)'
}

$_resolution = {
  "0": 1920,
  "1": 1440,
  "2": 1280,
  "3": 1024
}

for $i, $resolution in $maxBreakpoints

  @media all $resolution
```

And the output of this code is:

```
@media all ('and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1700px)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `all` into the string:

```
$maxBreakpoints = {
  "0": 'all and (min-width: 1701px) and (max-width: 1920px)',
  "1": 'all and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1700px)',
  "2": 'all and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1439px)',
  "3": 'all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1023px)'
}

$_resolution = {
  "0": 1920,
  "1": 1440,
  "2": 1280,
  "3": 1024
}

for $i, $resolution in $maxBreakpoints

  @media $resolution
```